# Connecting to a Windows server that has an active VPN connection

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop, tcpip, netbios

In my company we connect to various customers using VPN.
We have a dedicated Windows server where the VPN clients are installed, and if we need to do customer support, we have to physically log in to this server and connect.
We cannot log in to this server using RDP or VNC because most VPN clients do not allow split tunnels, and therefore prevent any other traffic using TCP/IP.

To overcome this problem, we installed [NetOp](http://www.netop.com/) on our PC's, and used NetBEUI to connect to the server. This is actually working pretty well when using XP on the clients. However, now we are upgrading to Windows 7, and I'm not sure if we would be able to use NetBEUI anymore.

My question is: is there any other way of connecting to a server that will not allow TCP/IP traffic? Any alternative network protocol that we can use? Any remote admin software that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A dedicated management card like Dell DRAC, IBM SupII, or HP iLo would do this.
2. An IP KVM would do this
3. Virtualizing the server and using the VMware console would do this
4. Using your network gear instead of this server to make the VPN connections to all of your clients would entirely sidestep the issue.

Comment: These are good suggestions! I hadn't thought of option 1 and 2 before.

Comment: I am hoping to solve my issue by using IP v6 for NetOp (haven´t tried yet), but I will accept you answer since you had some other good suggestions that I hadn´t thought of.